# `Test Case Timeout in robot framework with test case variable instead of variable defined in *** Variables *** section`

Tags: python, automated-tests, timeout, robotframework

```
*** Settings ***
Library         Collections
Documentation    Suite description
Test Timeout    60 minutes

*** Test Cases ***
Test title
${TEST_TIMEOUT1}  set variable  120   
log to console  ${TEST_TIMEOUT1}
[Timeout]  ${TEST_TIMEOUT1} minutes
```

I am trying to update the default Test Timeout of 60 minutes with Test case time `[TIMEOUT]` with variable `${TEST_TIMEOUT1}`.
I want to use a variable instead of hard-coded value.
with hard-coded value `[TIMEOUT]` is working fine.But facing below error if i use test case variable substitution

Setting test timeout failed: Variable '`${TEST_TIMEOUT1}`' not found.
Can you help how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test title
    ${TEST_TIMEOUT1}  set variable  120   
    log to console  ${TEST_TIMEOUT1}
    [Timeout]  ${TEST_TIMEOUT1} minutes
```

is not executed in this order. `[Timeout]` belongs to the test case setting, so it's executed *before* those first two lines. It's setting after all, so it makes sense to execute it first and then run the actual test steps.

Solution is easy, define `${TEST_TIMEOUT1}` outside the test case, for example:

```
*** Settings ***
Test Timeout    60 minutes

*** Variables ***
${TEST_TIMEOUT1}=    120 minutes

*** Test Cases ***
Test title
    [Timeout]  ${TEST_TIMEOUT1}
```

Then the default timeout will be 60 minutes, but in Test title it will be overriden and value of 120 minutes will be used.

Further readings:

- https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#settings-in-the-test-case-table
- https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#timeouts
- https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-case-timeout

Comment: Thank you...Actually i will be extracting TEST_TIMEOUT1 from a dictionary , and TEST_TIMEOUT1 is not direct key to extract, have to some addition few parameters and output will be stored in TEST_TIMEOUT1. so to read the dictionary and process the data i am doing inside test case and assigning value to TEST_TIMEOUT1.  Is there any other way that i can extract TEST_TIMEOUT1 in testcase and define variables again.?

Comment: Read the user guide and experiment. The bottom line is you need to set the variable before you use it in `[Timeout]`. The user guide shows a few examples here: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#user-keyword-timeout That's also how you need to do it.